# Visual Studio 2017 (v15.6.2) does not restart console after build

Tags: visual-studio-2017

as I said in title, after update to v15.6.2, VS does not restart console (ASP.NET Core project type) when I do rebuild (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>), so I have to manually restart it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) every time. (extremely sad, almost crying)

Before, I only need to run project once, when opened solution, and further rebuilds, just closes and then reopens console automagically.

Is this a VS bug? New feature? Maybe I've fat-fingered some project/build configuration?

Comment: It never once did that.  Simply pressing F5 (or Ctrl+F5) is the simple way, that builds the project *and* starts it.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it was. At least for ASP.NET Core projects it was. Added project type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost an year since I've asked this and finally found where this settings hides :D

Anyway, for anyone who want to save his fingers, make sure to check/set true
`Options -> Projects and Solutions -> ASP.NET Core -> Auto restart Kestrel server after build`.

This will restart it auto-magically after each build, so you don't have to always press another key to start it.

[image: Visual Studio - Auto restart Kestrel after build]
P.S.
It didn't took me a year to search for this option, just accidentally found it ;)